# sending FCM notification to all users that've installed my application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was told there was a way to send a notification to all the users of my application without the need of their FCM tokens.

if such a way exists how can it be done?

Comment: Create a topic, asign every user to the topic and send a notification for the "everyone" topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to do it is:

1- go to your firebase console, select your firebase project

2- select Cloud Messaging from the left menu.

3- send a new message and select all users.

**hint:** you must have added the FCM to your project

The second way to do it is:

from the server send to all users using thier Token, but you have to know each user token